# Convert date string into proper date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I get an array with dates as string from the server, now I want to filter only day, month and year. How can I format the filter result to a certain date format?

```
var date  = ['2015-02-04T23:54:00.000+01:00','2015-02-04T23:54:00.000+01:00', ...];

//wanted result: 2015-02-04 or 04.02.2015
```

Comment: How about using `new Date(STRING);` in loop ? And then, `dateObj.getMonth()`, `dateObj.getFullYear()`...

Comment: you can use moment for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert your what's look to be an ISO Date format like this:

```
var date  = ['2015-02-04T23:54:00.000+01:00','2015-02-04T23:54:00.000+01:00'];

date.map(function(_d) {
    var d = new Date(_d)
    return d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getMonth() + 1 + '-' + d.getDay()
}

// if you want to get fancy, you could throw in this function to pad the days and months:
var pad = function (n) {return n<10? '0'+n:''+n;}

var sorted = date.map(function(_d) {
    var d = new Date(_d)
    return d.getFullYear() + '-' + pad(d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(d.getDay())
})
console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: You can try `return d.toISOString().split('T')[0]`

Comment: If I use your suggestion, here is what I obtain : `2015-02-04`. Using mine, I have `2015-02-03`. How do you cope with the timezone part (`T23:54:00.000+01:00`)?

Comment: Well it works fine for me: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0o1otxho/). I have tried few timezones, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Date can take an argument of a string. Use a `for` loop to iterate through your list, and then make a new Date object for each one.

```
var date  = ['2015-02-04T23:54:00.000+01:00','2015-02-04T23:54:00.000+01:00']
var dateObjects = [];

for (var i = 0; i<date.length; i++) {
  d = new Date(date[i]);
  dateObjects.push(d);
}
```

Or, in a single line:

```
var dateObjects = date.map( function (datestr) {return new Date(datestr)} );
```

Now, you can find the month, day, and year from one of these by the following methods:

```
var year = dateObjects[0].getFullYear(); // Gets the year
var month = dateObjects[0].getMonth()+1; // Gets the month (add 1 because it's zero-based)
var day = dateObjects[0].getDate(); // Gets the day of the month
```

`dateObjects[0]` is just an example that refers to the first date in the list.

So you can then get your output string like

```
var dateStrings = dateObjects.map(function (item) {
  return item.getFullYear()+"-"+(item.getMonth()+1)+"-"+item.getDate();
})
```

Comment: You can try `Array.map` for this. `var dateObj = date.map(function(item){return new Date(item);});`

Answer (score 1):

```
var date  = ['2015-02-04T23:54:00.000+01:00','2015-02-04T23:54:00.000+01:00'];
var newdateobject = [];

$.each( date, function(key, e) {
var a = new Date(e);
  newdateobject.push(a.getFullYear()+'-'+(a.getMonth()+1) +'-'+a.getDate());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IF the format you mentioned is consistent, then:

```
date.forEach(function(d) {
    d = d.substring(0, 10);
})
```

Comment: Will work in most of the cases but what if date is `2015-2-4T23:54:00.000+01:00` ?

Comment: as I said, if the format is consistent. If the format is inconsistent, then I don't think there is any cross browser compliant solution. Even `new Date`'s implementation is inconsistent in case of converting strings to dates.